# Simple Acl controlled app error...in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have followed the steps for Acl controlled application in cakephp cookbook. And while following the steps and creating Acldb i got this error. This error occurs whenever i try to login from users login....

Error is

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn&#039;t find Aro node identified by &quot;Array ( [Aro0.model] =&gt; Group [Aro0.foreign_key] =&gt; 2 ) &quot;
```

I have searched a lot but couldnt solve this error can anyone please help me out...

Answer (score 1):

The Aro (Group) with id=2 does not exist in your aros table.

Check the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html#creating-access-request-objects-aros-and-access-control-objects-acos) to see how you can add AROs.